# Is there a way to view word files locally using office web viewer

Tags: html, django, http, url, https

I have a word file, and I want to open up that word file for preview/viewing purposes only, not to edit. How could I go by this?

I have a Django application and one of the main purpose of the application is to view documents that people upload on the site. However for testing purposes I cannot get to preview documents for reasons I do not know.

I am using [Microsoft office viewer](https://products.office.com/en-US/office-online/view-office-documents-online?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=3bf22f4e-ec2c-40c2-a577-9f2db59fe706) to view the files.

This is my html code in Django:

```
<iframe
src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/project/1/f73ab109-dcaa-4cc3-bbfc-7121eca10118.doc">
</iframe>
```

And of course `media/project/1/f73ab109-dcaa-4cc3-bbfc-7121eca10118.doc` is the location of the file. The error displayed in the html:

[image]

I am assuming that the office viewer is expecting a "real" internet directory and not something locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.

To open a file from something like Office Viewer, the file must be accessible from anywhere on the Internet.
"127.0.0.1" is your local loopback address, which is accessible only from your computer, so the Office Viewer can not access.

Even in a test environment, you will need to upload the media file to public storage and make it accessible from the Internet.

Deploy your Django App to a publicly hosted instance, or use Django-Storage app to serve MEDIA files from a public storage service such as AWS S3.

Comment: This is great except for the rare case where the files are semi-sensitive and should not be publicly available